# Laravel form include input in action attribute

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

***LARAVEL*** 5.0
**PHP**     5.4.45

I have a route that is shaped like this :

***/app/Http/routes.php***

```
Route::get('/clients/search/{id}', 'ClientController@searchById')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('/clients/search/{text}', 'ClientController@searchByText')->where('text', '[a-zA-Z]');
```

I will not print my view here but it simply search for the exact client (case id) or the first 10 clients (case text).

Then I want to create a search form. I created the route :

***/app/Http/routes.php***

```
// Route::get('/clients/search/{id}', 'ClientController@searchById')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
// Route::get('/clients/search/{text}', 'ClientController@searchByText')->where('text', '[a-zA-Z]');
Route::get( '/clients/search', 'ClientController@search');
```

The controller for this route :

***/app/Http/Controllers/ClientController.php***

```
<?php    

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;

class ClientController extends Controller {
    // Controllers for the 'searchById' and 'searchByText'

    public function search() {
        return view('client.search.search', [
            'title'     =>  'Client search form',
            'title_sub' =>  ''
        ]); 
    }
}
```

And the view for this search form :

***/ressources/view/client/search/search.blade.php***

```
<form action="/clients/search/INPUT HERE ?" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="newpassword" class="form-control" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Id de client, nom, prénom, ...">              
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="button_search" class="btn green-haze" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**QUESTION**

How can I, before submit, pass an input as a part of my `action` attribute for my form ? The point is to be able to launch those kind of requests :

- /clients/search/26
- /clients/search/Mike%20%Folley
- /clients/search/Paris

So my controllers handling this route could do the job. Is there any way to do that ? Or should I go for JavaScript solution (*which make me sad a bit*) ?

Comment: If you want to change the form's action attribute you'd have to use JavaScript. But why exactly do you need that? In order to help your routes decide between two search controllers? Wouldn't it be better to have a single search controller which inside its code will decide -- depending on the type of the search term -- whether to search by id or by name?

Comment: Depending it is a text or an id, my view is not the same : If it is an id, each client having an unique Id in database, I fetch the exact client information so my view is different. If it is a text search, it may have several clients that match this text (for example : Searching for "mike", there could be multiple "Mike" in database so I fetch them in an array and not a specific client aimed view). I managed to make the search work using JavaScript. Maybe if I take the problem another way I could have managed using forms parameters . Too tricky to be possible I guess.

Comment: One controller can return different views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need javascript to modify request URL before it is even sent :). No form tag needed for that, vanilla js approach like this might be sufficient:

```
<input type="text" id="search">

<button onclick="search()">
Submit
</button>

<script>
function search() {
  window.location='/search/' + 
    encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('search').value);
}
</script>
```

You can and should just use one route and then in controller's method decide on what to search and what view to return. Routes should contain the least amount of logic possible.